# DNS resolution using a VM under libvirt

Tags: domain-name-system, centos, fedora, freeipa

I have a Fedora 36 laptop with libvirt configured and run free-IPA server, based on CentOS 8 as a virtual machine. The IP address of this IPA server is 192.168.122.20 and my host laptop has an IP address of 192.168.1.50/24

Now I have another physical workstation and I'm trying to install the oVirt-hosted engine and would like to use IPA as my DNS server. Given that the IPA server is a guest and is not exposed to the 192.168.1.0/24 network, how can I achieve DNS resolution via the IPA server?

Comment: i flagged your question for movement due home and enduser questions are offtopic on serverfault. you could use the same why by flag your question due community reasons and click on bellongs to a other site and choose superuser.com. - there is no penalty for that ;-)

Comment: The obvious answer here appears to be "expose your FreeIPA server on the 192.168.1.0/24 network", which you could do either by directly attaching it to the network (create a bridge with your primary NIC, or create a macvlan device), or by setting up the necessary netfilter to rules to expose the DNS ports.